# Is the filtered colimit of sheaves of abelian groups a sheaf?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory

This might be embarrassingly simple, but I want to be 100% sure I am not missing any subtleties. Let $F_i$, $i\in I$ be a filtered inductive system of sheaves of abelian groups on some site. Take the presheaf colimit $F$. It seems to me that $F$ is a sheaf. Is this true?

It seems to be a consequence of the following: let $\{U_j\longrightarrow U\}_{j
\in J}$ be a covering. Then, for each $i\in I$, $F_i$ being a sheaf, we know that:

$$F_i(U)=lim(\prod_{j\in J}F_i(U_j)\overset{\longrightarrow}{\underset{\longrightarrow}{ }} \prod_{j,j'\in J}F_i(U_j\times_UU_{j'})$$

Now, because filtered colimits commute with finite limits for abelian groups,
it follows that $F$ is a sheaf. Did I miss something?

Comment: No, that is not correct.  You can look at Exercise II.1.10 in Hartshorne.  For example, let $X$ be an infinite set with the discrete topology.  Let $I$ be the directed system of finite subsets $S$ of $X$, ordered by inclusion.  For every $S$, let $F_S$ be the extension by $0$ of the sheaf of locally constant $\mathbb{Z}$-valued functions on $S$.  Then the colimit sheaf is the sheaf of $\mathbb{Z}$-valued functions on $X$.  But since every $F_S(X)$ is zero, the colimit presheaf has only the zero global section.

Comment: Thanks a lot. If you have a moment, could you tell me where exactly I am going wrong in the reasoning above? Thanks

Comment: Okay! I see! The filtered colimit doesn't commute with the possibly infinite products in those brackets! Thanks :)

Comment: That, by the way, tells you what the correct condition is: your inductive system needs to be $\kappa$-filtered for a regular cardinal $\kappa$ that is sufficiently large.

Answer (score 6):

Your proof works if the covering is finite. Hence, the claim is true for noetherian sites. The corresponding statement for sheaf cohomology is also true, see Stacks Project, [Tag 0739](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0739). But in general filtered colimits (of abelian groups, doesn't really matter) don't commute with infinite products. For example, the canonical map $\mathrm{colim}_n ~\prod_{i \in I} \frac{1}{n} \mathbb{Z} \to \prod_{i \in I} \mathrm{colim}_n \frac{1}{n} \mathbb{Z} = \prod_{i \in I} \mathbb{Q}$ is not surjective when $I$ is infinite, since the denominators of a rational sequence don't have to be bounded. As soon as you have an example for $\mathrm{colim}_n \prod_{i \in I} A_{n,i} \not\cong \prod_{i \in I} \mathrm{colim}_n A_{n,i}$, this is is witnessed by sheaves: Take $X = \sqcup_{i \in I} X_i$ with connected $X_i$ (or just points) and consider the sheaves $\underline{A_{n,i}}$ on $X_i$ which glue to a sheaf $A_n$ on $X$. Then the presheaf colimit $\mathrm{colim}_n A_n$ is not a sheaf.